# PHP 5.3 data storage

Tags: php, php-5.3

I was asked in my interview question there is a convenient PHP function you can save a data without saving into the database for later use as of PHP 5.3 and I couldn't answer this question.

Can anyone help me find out what that is?

Comment: Session, memcache, apc, wincache, xcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save data to a lot of places. The most obvious is probably:

```
setcookie("MyCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", ".example.com", 0);
```

or

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['somekey'] = $someval;
```

Comment: That's what I've told them (either session or cookie or HTML5 local storage) but is there a new function introduced in PHP 5.3?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.functions.php - nothing jumps out as a new data storage ability.